# Is crontab's @reboot entry triggered after X has started?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, startup, cron

Using `crontab -e` I have added an entry to my cron tab file

```
@reboot /home/rene/misc/change-layout.sh
```

`change-layout.sh` contains some `xmodmap -e` statements to change to keyboard layout.

When I restart the computer, it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Yet, when I start the script on a shell, the keyboard layout is changed. So the problem cannot be with the script.

So my question is: when is `@reboot` actually triggered, specifically, is it triggered after `X` is started so that it can have an effect?

Since it is not working, is there a better place have my script executed when I start up the system?

Comment: Not answering your question in regards to timing of `@reboot` in `cron`, but there can be issues around `cron` not having the `$PATH` environment variable defined in the same way as a user in an interactive session.

Comment: "Yet, when I start the script on a shell, the keyboard layout is changed. So the problem cannot be with the script." That I would not be so sure about. "cron" acts differently than a normal shell. PATH, environment and plenty more things that could be off. Plus if there is no DISPLAY defined it might be stopping the script .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cron is started before X. You can use "sleep" and the "at" command to stall executions but ... that's just a weird hack.

If the script needs X: see "startup applications" in "dash". That is started on logon to the desktop.