# Script Isn't Working at Reboot

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, xinput

In this thread [Temporarily Disable Touchscreen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441793/temporarily-disable-touchscreen) I asked how could I disable my HP touchscreen. By trial and error, and using the command

```
xinput --list
```

I was able to identify which device was the touchscreen and by typing

```
xinput disable id
```

being the id the device's actual number, I can disable the touchscreen.

The problem is that I have to do this every time I turn on my pc. Furthermore, depending if I turn on my computer with the mouse or not, the touchscreen changes its id.

I want to write a script that disables the touchscreen automatically every time I turn on the laptop so I need to take this in account. In the script I wrote

```
cd /home/user/Desktop/touchscreen_ids

xinput --list | grep "ELAN" | grep "slave  pointer" > id.txt
```

(the first command goes to this particular folder and the second writes the following text in txt file

```
⎜   ↳ ELAN2514:00 04F3:2AF4                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

). Then, still in the same script I wrote

```
sed -i 's/id=/\nid=/g' id.txt

sed -i 's/\[/\n\[/g' id.txt

cat id.txt | grep "id=" > iso_id.txt

sed -i 's/id=//g' iso_id.txt

touchscreen_id=$(cat iso_id.txt)

xinput disable $touchscreen_id
```

This works well when I run the script. However, using the cron tab @reboot option, when I turn on the pc, it creates the txt files but they are empty and the touchscreen is enabled.

Do you guys have any clue about what's going on here? I am not very experienced with Linux or the command line, so please try to keep it simple.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is the kind of thing that's probably better done via your desktop's Startup Applications - see [Is crontab's @reboot entry triggered after X has started?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747399/is-crontabs-reboot-entry-triggered-after-x-has-started)

Comment: @steeldriver worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help - btw you shouldn't need to jump through so many hoops to get the device ID - something like `xinput list --id-only '<name-of-device>'` should return it directly

Comment: @steeldriver you are right, it is much simpler than what I was doing! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

cron jobs' environment is not your own, so use one of the mechanisms bash supplies to run your script. From the bash man page:

```
executes /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
```

Run your script from .bash_login (or one of the others).  .profile was the traditional place, which would work with some non-bash shells.

Comment: You are saying that I need to type the path to the script in one of the above options and that would run my scripts every time I turned on my pc?

Comment: ./yourscript should be all you need in the .profile, etc.

Comment: I get it now. I'll try it, thanks!